# create custom markup in forge viewer

Tags: svg, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, markup-extensions

I want to create custom markup which is rectangle and contains (textbox/ callout) as inner markup behave as a single markup.
I have attached screen short: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS8dn.png
The issue I am facing right now are listed below :

1. show textbox/ callout at bottom - inside rectangle markup we draw.
2. when we drag rectangle markup the inner collout/textbox needs to drag along with it's outer rectangle.
3. we should restrict drag and drop of inner textbox/callout seperately.
4. Inner textbox/callout should be editable.

I want it to be displayed as this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaoWh.png
and outer rectangle markup should be draggable along with inner textbox/callout.

Comment: Why are you using SVG in this case? Sounds like a better solution would be to use HTML with the drag'n'drop API and contenteditable.

Comment: right, but how can we create html for draw llike this -(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaoWh.png) .

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen our blog post [Implementing Custom Markups](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups)? In the sample we're creating a single `<path>` element but you can generate more complex shapes as well, e.g., a `<group>` of a rectangle and a text element (in the `updateStyle` method).

However, making the text element editable might be a bit tricky with this approach. If text editing is critical for your use case, you could consider overlaying the viewer with actual HTML elements as [@chrwahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322084/chrwahl) suggested. For example, in our [Digital Twin](https://aps-digital-twin.autodesk.io) demo we're using floating HTML labels to show issues assigned to individual design elements: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-digital-twin/blob/develop/public/scripts/extensions/issues.js.